# IronPdf - How to add a blank page with an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ironpdf

I have a signature image that I want to insert into the end of a document. I have this signature available in base64 format or binary. I believe this can be achieved using somethink like this piece of code:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
PdfImage image = PdfImage.FromFile("path/to/image.jpg");
PdfGraphics graphics = PdfGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
graphics.DrawImage(image, new RectangleF(50, 50, 200, 200));
document.Save("path/to/document.pdf");
```

The problem is that the .AddPage method doesn't exist, I tried .AddBlankPage but it doesn't exist neither. What similar method or approach I can use?

Versioning:

```
<PackageReference Include="ironpdf.linux" Version="2022.10.9622" />
<PackageReference Include="IronPdf.Slim" Version="2022.10.9622" />
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://ironpdf.com/how-to/signing/

Comment: User09939 comment will likely work, but it sounds like you are more interested in just adding an image of a signature rather than digitally signing the PDF (and including an image of the signature).  I can get an image to show up on its own page by creating a separate PdfDocument and then `.Merge`ing the two PDFs, but its not very pretty (it seems to just slap it [into the middle of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUzKW.png)).  This library isn't very good for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User09939's comment solved it. I used .merge to add a page with an img element

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).